# Bash - Listing directories only

Tags: shell, directory, ls

I can't list directories only with the command:

```
ls -d
```

It shows me only the current directory `.`, but there are a lot more than that.

I'm using a Linux Mint 18 Sarah.

Answer (score 3):

The command `ls -d */` does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `-d` option is strange. I was dissapointed by `ls` many times, so I learnt `find`. To list non-recursively (`-maxdepth 1`) local (`.`) directories (`-type d`):

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. Is there actually a `ls` command that shows only directories. There has to be one since it is such a basic task to list only directories and no files. Or could you specify what the problem could be?

Comment: I wasn't able to do it with `ls`, sorry. It seems simple, but `-d` option doesn't do anything usable.